# VBA Sub or function not defined error in while calling public/private sub in a Class

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script like below:

```
Sub button_click ()
'
' < some code >
'
     call FindStrings (strfolder, Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub FindStrings(strFolder As String, Optional wksSheet As Worksheet = Nothing)
'
' < some code>
'
     Call ProcessFolder(strFolder, strIndent, varStrings, varMatchesFound, varFileNames, lngFolderCount, lngFileCount)

End sub

Private Sub ProcessFolder(strFolder As String, ByRef strIndent As String, ByRef varStrings As Variant, ByRef varMatchesFound As Variant, ByRef varFileNames As Variant, ByRef lngFolderCount As Long, lngFileCount As Long)
'
' < some code>
'
Call ProcessFile(objFile.Path, strIndent, varStrings, varMatchesFound, varFileNames)

End sub

Private Sub ProcessFile(strFullPath As String, ByRef strIndent As String, ByRef varStrings As Variant, ByRef varMatchesFound As Variant, ByRef varFileNames As Variant)
'
' < some code>
'
End sub
```

Currently, `button_click` and `FindStrings` are in a `Module` and `ProcessFolder` and `ProcessFile` are in a `Class`.

When I run the `button_click` sub-routine, it throws an error:

> Sub or function not defined

The error occurs in on the `Call ProcessFolder...` line in **FindStrings**.

I have searched many issues relating to the error **Sub or function not defined** and also tried to implement the changes they answers suggest to rectify this error, but it is not working.

Any help regarding what this error is and how to rectify it would be appreciated.

Comment: are those all in the same module?

Comment: No I had placed the button_click () and FindStrings () in standard module, ProcessFolder () and ProcessFile () in class module, because I found someone mentioned that it might solve the error but it also dint worked . They are in four different modules @TimWilliams

Comment: I would start by putting them all in the same module

Comment: A `Private` function/subroutine is only accessible from other functions/subroutines within the same module.  It is best to put the button_click subroutine in the same object as the button (usually a worksheet) and then all your utility functions into a single code module, but ensure that the "entry point" (in your case `FindStrings`) is declared `Public`.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `Call Module1.SubName()` fix your problem? Also, ditto to what YowE3K said.

Comment: @Tyeler - if `SubName` was declared to be `Private`, even including the `Module1.` qualifier won't work.  It has to be declared `Public` to be exposed outside the object (i.e. code module in this case) in which it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling methods within a `Class` from within a `Module` then you need to *instantiate* the class with the `New` keyword. You then refer to the `Class` methods with dot notation.

A general example would be:

```
'Module
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim o As Class1
    Set o = New Class1
    o.Bar
End Sub

'Class1
Public Sub Bar()
    MsgBox "Hello world"
End Sub
```

Which means for your example you would do:

```
'Module
Sub button_click ()
'< some code >
     Call FindStrings (strfolder, Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub FindStrings(strFolder As String, Optional wksSheet As Worksheet = Nothing)
' < some code>
     Dim o As YourClass
     Set o = New YourClass
     o.ProcessFolder(strFolder, strIndent, varStrings, varMatchesFound, varFileNames, lngFolderCount, lngFileCount)

End Sub

'YourClass
Public Sub ProcessFolder(strFolder As String, ByRef strIndent As String, ByRef varStrings As Variant, ByRef varMatchesFound As Variant, ByRef varFileNames As Variant, ByRef lngFolderCount As Long, lngFileCount As Long)
' < some code>
    Call ProcessFile(objFile.Path, strIndent, varStrings, varMatchesFound, varFileNames)

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFile(strFullPath As String, ByRef strIndent As String, ByRef varStrings As Variant, ByRef varMatchesFound As Variant, ByRef varFileNames As Variant)
' < some code>
End Sub
```

Note that:

- In `FindStrings` you need to create a new instance of `YourClass`
- In `YourClass` the `ProcessFolder` sub-routine needs to be `Public`